# About memory release for a binary tree object in C++

Tags: c++, memory

I am confused about the method of memory release. Which one is correct?

way 1

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;
    TreeNode() : val(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
    TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
    TreeNode(int x, TreeNode *left, TreeNode *right) : val(x), left(left), right(right) {}
};

int main()
{
    TreeNode *t1 = new TreeNode(1, new TreeNode(2), new TreeNode(3));
    delete t1;
    return 0;
}
```

way 2

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;
    TreeNode() : val(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
    TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
    TreeNode(int x, TreeNode *left, TreeNode *right) : val(x), left(left), right(right) {}
};

int main()
{
    TreeNode *t1 = new TreeNode(1, new TreeNode(2), new TreeNode(3));
    delete t1->left;
    delete t1->right;
    delete t1;
    return 0;
}
```

By disassembly view in vscode, I can know the address of the line.

```
delete t1; // Ox0000000100003dd4 ldur x8, [x29, #-0x10]
```

When running the line, no change occurs. I don't get 'ldur x8, [x29, #-0x10],' and I don't know if the memory is exactly released. Please tell me what I should learn to figure it out. Thanks for your help.

After reading the helpful comments, I have revised the code. One version is without smart pointers, and the other version is with smart pointers.

without smart pointers

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;

    TreeNode() : val(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {
        cout << "create node " << val << endl;
    }
    TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {
        cout << "create node " << val << endl;
    }
    TreeNode(int x, TreeNode *left, TreeNode *right) : val(x), left(left), right(right) {
        cout << "create node " << val << endl;
    }
    ~TreeNode(){
        if (left != nullptr) {
            delete left;
            left = nullptr;
        }
        if (right != nullptr) {
            delete right;
            right = nullptr;
        }
        cout << "delete node " << val <<endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
    TreeNode *t = new TreeNode(1, new TreeNode(2), new TreeNode(3));
    delete t;

    return 0;
}
```

with smart pointers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

struct TreeNode {
    int val;
    unique_ptr<TreeNode> left;
    unique_ptr<TreeNode> right;

    TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {
        cout << "create node " << val << endl;
    }
    TreeNode(int x, unique_ptr<TreeNode> l, unique_ptr<TreeNode> r) : val(x), left(move(l)), right(move(r)) {
        cout << "create node " << val << endl;
    }
    ~TreeNode() {
        cout << "delete node " << val << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    unique_ptr<TreeNode> t1 = make_unique<TreeNode>(1, make_unique<TreeNode>(2), make_unique<TreeNode>(3));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use ```valgrind``` that will tell you about memory leaks.

Comment: For that particular code, the second example will work correctly. The first leaks memory. But when you have more nodes in the tree you don't want to delete every node manually. The destructor for `Treenode` should delete the node's two children. For every `new` there should be exactly one `delete`; for every `new[]` there should be exactly one `delete[]`.

Comment: Neither one is correct. The correct one should destroy the children in the destructor.

Comment: You should either follow the rule of zero, and use smart pointers which you don't need to explicitly delete. Or if you want to handle the explicit memory management yourself then you should create a destructor that deletes the sub-trees. And follow [the rules of three or five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: The `TreeNode` is an example of an object that does **not** own the data pointed to by its pointers.  I call that kind of non-owning pointer a "view" or "view pointer".  The code is a bit fragile though, because main is manually managing the destruction of the non-owning pointers in the `TreeNode`.  There are several ways that could be improved, which would protect against leaking if an exception is thrown.

Comment: To expand on my previous comment, your `TreeNode` should take *ownership* of its two child-nodes. And so on all the way down to the leaves. So the recommendation is to use `std::unique_ptr` which gives single ownership semantics. If you use `std::unique_ptr` then you can follow the *rule of zero*, where you don't need to create a destructor, copy-constructor, copy-assignment operator etc.

Comment: Note: when you `delete` an object you are promising the system that you no longer need this object. The system takes it from there. It probably doesn't free the storage because that has a cost, and you may pay again if the storage was returned and you need that storge again later. How much memory the program uses is difficult to measure because it could be sitting on a trove of storage that it may use again later.

Comment: In addition, modern processors employ virtual memory to optimize and make things really muddy. Your program may request and be granted storage, but the storage may not actually materialize until it is used. It may have been granted and assigned, but saved off to a slower media to allow a program that needs more storage *now* to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule is simple; For every "new" you must have a matching "delete".

It would usually be the responsibility of the container class (or allocator passed into the container) to manage the lifetime of the nodes within it. A Node should not attempt to delete its own children, that is the job of whatever container you create for your node type.

As for the disassembly, don’t expect to see the code which does the deallocation of memory in your program.
That’s part of the C++ Runtime and is provided by the compiler/OS not your code (unless you explicitly override it for example in embedded systems).